# Who first coined the phrase "aviate, navigate, communicate"?

Tags: aviation-history, terminology

The phrase *"aviate, navigate, communicate"* describes the priorities of tasks for a pilot. It is applicable to a wide variety of situations, including military scenarios and emergencies.

Who first introduced this phrase, and when did it first appear in the aviation community?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the genesis of the phrase, but I heard several WWII era military pilots interleave it with stories of their sorties, and of the debriefs for those sorties.  Based upon that, I would say that the expression dates back to at least the early-1940's.